# Material design App bar with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, menu

I need to style a Navigation bar like the App bar on material design apps with CSS. For example Google-Keep app or Playstore app. In this Navigation bar are a title and a simple menu.

What i have is a content div and two fixed div on the top. One of them is always fixed and the other one has a negative margin-top on scroll. But, if i scroll down, there is a short "blink"-effect and i don't know why.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  
    var lastScrollY = 0;
    var lastScrollDownY = 0;
    var lastScrollUpY = 0;
    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scrollY = $(this).scrollTop();
        
        // detect scroll down / up
        if(scrollY < lastScrollY)
        {
         var diffScroll = lastScrollDownY - scrollY;
            if(diffScroll > 105)
            {
                diffScroll = 105;
            }
            var navbarY = -105+diffScroll;
            $("#navbar-bottom").css({
                "margin-top":navbarY+"px"
            });
            lastScrollUpY = scrollY;
        } else {
          var diffScroll2 = lastScrollDownY - lastScrollUpY;
            if(diffScroll2 > 105)
            {
                diffScroll2 = 105;
            }
            $("#navbar-bottom").css({
                "margin-top":"-"+diffScroll2+"px"
            });
            lastScrollDownY = scrollY;
        }
        
        lastScrollY = scrollY;
    });
    
});
```

```css
body {
  height:100%;
}
#header {
  width:100%;
}
#navbar-top {
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  z-index:1000;
  height:35px;
  background-color:#1976D2;
}
#navbar-bottom {
  width: 100%;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 z-index: 999;
  height:105px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
#navbar-bottom .navbar {
  padding-top: 35px;
}
#wrapper {
  padding-top: 105px;
  position: relative;
  height:2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="navbar-top">
            ActionBar (always fixed)
        </div>
        <div id="navbar-bottom">
            <div class="navbar">
                Menu links here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Seems like the blink is caused as if you scroll slightly, you start off with a margin top of -65px.  If you are wanting to have the navbar bottom scroll with the content, why not just put it in the wrapper?

Comment: -65px on which section? As default css value or the scroll down value?
Because the navbar bottom should only scroll with content by scrolling down. When scrolling up, the navbar should "scroll in" on the actual scroll postion.

Comment: I think it is this bit that causes it: `var navbarY = -105+diffScroll;`. if you do a `console.log` on this variable, you will see that it starts off as a negative

Comment: Thank you! I've replaced it just with a transform. See answer from K. Daniek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Added `transform: translateY()`, which is much more dynamic then just changing the `margin-top` property. Check it out and tell me if it does satisfy you, if not - let me know and I will try to improve it.

https://jsfiddle.net/pfj9j8md/

```js
var lastScrollY = 0;
 var lastScrollDownY = 0;
 var lastScrollUpY = 0;

 $(window).scroll(function() {
   var scrollY = $(this).scrollTop();

   // detect scroll down / up
   if (scrollY < lastScrollY) {
     var diffScroll = lastScrollDownY - scrollY;
     if (diffScroll > 105) {
       diffScroll = 105;
     }
     var navbarY = -105 + diffScroll;
     $("#navbar-bottom").css({
       'transform': 'translateY(0)'
     });
     lastScrollUpY = scrollY;
   } else {
     var diffScroll2 = lastScrollDownY - lastScrollUpY;
     if (diffScroll2 > 105) {
       diffScroll2 = 105;
     }
     $("#navbar-bottom").css({
       'transform': 'translateY(-200px)'
     });
     lastScrollDownY = scrollY;
   }

   lastScrollY = scrollY;
 });
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
}
#navbar-top {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #1976D2;
}
#navbar-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 105px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
#navbar-bottom .navbar {
  padding-top: 35px;
}
#wrapper {
  padding-top: 105px;
  position: relative;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="navbar-top">
      ActionBar (always fixed)
    </div>
    <div id="navbar-bottom">
      <div class="navbar">
        Menu links here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
      sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
      Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is exactly the way how it should look. This is amazin, you're ma todays rescuer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a smooth animation for the submenu:

```
#navbar-bottom {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 105px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    transition: all 500ms;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var lastScrollY = 0;
  var lastScrollDownY = 0;
  var lastScrollUpY = 0;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollY = $(this).scrollTop();

    // detect scroll down / up
    if (scrollY < lastScrollY) {
      var diffScroll = lastScrollDownY - scrollY;
      if (diffScroll > 105) {
        diffScroll = 105;
      }
      var navbarY = -105 + diffScroll;
      $("#navbar-bottom").css({
        "margin-top": navbarY + "px"
      });
      lastScrollUpY = scrollY;
    } else {
      var diffScroll2 = lastScrollDownY - lastScrollUpY;
      if (diffScroll2 > 105) {
        diffScroll2 = 105;
      }
      $("#navbar-bottom").css({
        "margin-top": "-" + diffScroll2 + "px"
      });
      lastScrollDownY = scrollY;
    }

    lastScrollY = scrollY;
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
}
#navbar-top {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #1976D2;
}
#navbar-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 105px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  transition: all 500ms;
}
#navbar-bottom .navbar {
  padding-top: 35px;
}
#wrapper {
  padding-top: 105px;
  position: relative;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="navbar-top">
      ActionBar (always fixed)
    </div>
    <div id="navbar-bottom">
      <div class="navbar">
        Menu links here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
      sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
      Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```